# Exploring Convergence and Root Determination with Fixed-Point Iteration

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, fixed-point-theorems

##### Understanding Fixed-Point Iteration: Exploring Convergence and Root Determination

The equation $$2x^2 - 7x + 6 = 0$$ has two positive roots. We aim to determine these using the following fixed-point iteration:
$$
x_{k+1} = \frac{{8x_k - 2x_k^2}}{{k - 6}}
$$

**a)** It is found that only the larger of the two roots can be determined using this method. Explain why, for example using the figure below.

[image]

**Solution:** Denote the right-hand side of the iteration as $$\phi(x) = 9x - 2x^2 - 6.$$ For convergence, it is required that $$|\phi'(x^*)| < 1$$ where $x^*$ is the root. The figure shows that $\phi$ has a slope of zero at the largest root, and therefore converges towards it. At the smallest root, $\phi$ has a slope greater than $x = y$. Since the latter has a slope of one, the iteration diverges here.

**My question** the solution is more confusing than the question. I have no idea what they are doing why they changed 8 with a 9. How in the hell the function has a slope 0 for the largest solution which is x=3. Can anyone help me understand what is going on? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: $x=3$ is not a root of the first equation.

Comment: There should not be a quotient in the first recursion formula. It should be $x_{k+1}=8x_k-2x_k^2-6$. Also the $9$ instead of $8$ in the $\phi$ formula appears to be a typo.

Comment: @Moo no not really.

Comment: The equation whose roots you are finding is $\color{red}{\mathbf 7}x - 2x^2 - 6 = 0$. The graphs are of $y = \color{red}{\mathbf 8}x - 2x^2 - 6$ and $y = x$. If $7x - 2x^2 - 6 = 0$ then $8x - 2x^2 - 6 = x$. I.e., the roots you are after are not where $y=8x - 2x^2 - 6$ crosses the $x$-axis, but where $y=8x - 2x^2 - 6$ crosses the line $y = x$, and the higher of those two points is at $x = 2$.

Comment: FYI - I am not sure what algorithm they are using here, but it seems highly likely that the $k$ in the denominator is another typo, and should instead be $x_k$. As is, the sequence of $x_k$ could only either converge to $0$ or diverge.